# Java regex matching to replace substrings

Tags: java, regex, replace

How can I replace all occurences of java substrings like stuff="-9888777666" , stuff="123", with the substring stuff="0"? The double quotes are actually a part of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [regular expressions explanation in the java docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum):

```
string = string.replaceAll("stuff=\"-?\\d+\"", "stuff=\"0\"");
```

Comment: I tried this temp.replaceAll("stuff=\"\\w+\"", "stuff=\"0\"");

But it does not work. The string remains as it was. Please note that there is a string enclosed within the double quotes in the substring stuff="foo".

Comment: \w does not match a dash. Other than that I just ran the code, it replaces your example (`stuff="-9888777666" , stuff="123"`) perfectly.